# Resolution and other characteristics of multipatch

Tags: resolution, multipatch

i'm trying to understand how multipatch works. I have one element and i would like to change its resolution and position. when i try to change the position, there are limits for that, only can move this in Y 10 units ande X-Z 0.1 units ¿someone know how can i move it, are the limits adjustable?. i'm thinking it's probably that the domain has a important roll in this case, but i couldn't modify this one ¿is that possible?

When i try to change the resolution, in the moment of import 3D files i can to modify XYZ resolution and tolerance, but then when i check this items in the multipatch, they dont have the values introduced by me. ¿are these characteristics adjustable?

i don't know, perhaps these characteristics are stipulated by default depending on kind of archive and they are not adjustable. ¿Does anyone have any ideas about this?